# ffmpeg combine three videos side by side

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have three videos s1.mp4,s2.mp4 s3.mp4 and I need to combine three videos side by side I know use hstack but my three videos has different size?

I've found  following commands.It works,but only support two videos.

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp4 -i s2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base];[base][wm]hstack=2" final.mp4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i s1.mp4 -i s2.mp4 -i s3.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih[1v][0v];[2:v][0v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih[2v][0v];[0v][1v][2v]hstack=3,scale='2*trunc(iw/2)':'2*trunc(ih/2)'" final.mp4
```

Comment: I tried with this code,strill without any luck 
`[libx264 @ 0x7f9334838e00] width not divisible by 2 (637x160)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height` @Gyan

Comment: Added filter at end

Comment: Can you tell me How to use "VSTACK" in this case? @Gyan